# vue v-model does not seem to be working in modal

Tags: vue.js, v-model

I am pretty new to vue, and am trying to use it in a bootstrap modal.  The relevant div in the modal is as follows.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="priceQCField" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Price<span class="red"> *</span></label>
    <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control col-sm-4" id="priceQCField" name="priceQCField" min="0" v-model="job.price">   
</div>
```

I read some other questions about vue returning strings rather than numbers, so I have converted the job.price to a number inside my method to call the modal

```
showPriceJob: function (job) {
    this.job = job;
    this.job.price = parseFloat(this.job.price);
    $('#mdlPriceJob').modal('show');
},
```

However, job.price refuses to appear in the input field either as a string or a number. I know it is available to the modal as I can see it using `<span>{{job.price}}</span>`.

Can anyone advise me please?

Additional - I think it is a display issue - if I change the input field, the entry in the `<span>` changes

2nd update - initial table

```
<tr class="light-grey" v-for="job in jobs" v-on:click="viewJob(job)">
    <td>{{job.id}}</td>
    <td>{{job.customerName}}</td>
    <td>{{job.description}}</td>
    <td v-bind:class="job.dueDate | dateColour">{{job.dueDate | dateOnly}}</td>
    <td>&pound;{{job.price}} {{job.isEstimate | priceEstimated}}</td>
    <td>{{job.delivery}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: could you change the order of changing job.price and showing modal ?

Comment: Use a computed property instead of v-model, so that when it changes somewhere, it reflects in your bootstrap modal

Comment: Qonvex620 - I tried this without success - it didn't appear either with or without the parseFloat

Comment: maestro.inc - not quiote sure what you mean - can you explain it further?

Comment: @NikWhite, do you have some error messages within your browser console?

Answer (score 0):

**Upd.**

According to your comments to my answer you are using `v-for` and you can't use `this.job` within your method. You should give us more code to see the whole picture.

**Upd.2**

You have showed more code but I didn't see any v-for so I am confused. You can try to use something like this if `job` is a property of `appData.jobs`:

```
        showPriceJob: function (job) {
            this.appData.jobs.job = Object.assign({}, job);
            this.appData.jobs.job = parseFloat(this.appData.jobs.job.price);
            $('#mdlPriceJob').modal('show');
        },
```

But I'm not sure about this because I don't see where `job` is declared.

**Upd.3**

Oh! Wait! You have this code:

`data: appData.jobs`, but `data` should be in this format:

```
data: function(){
    return {
        appData: {
            jobs: [],
        },
    }
},
```

Or show me what is your `appData.jobs` variable is.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Comment: @NikWhite, Can you show the declaration of `job` within  `data`?

Comment: - is this what you need to see?     var jobs = new Vue({
            el: '#appJobs',
            data: appData.jobs,
            methods: {

Comment: @NikWhite, Yes, it is. What is `appData.jobs`? Where is your `job` property?

Comment: @NikWhite , are you using that code within `v-for`?

Comment: appData is a dynamic js file created through a php class
        $appData['jobs']['jobs'] = Job::getQCData();
        $appData['jobs']['job'] = array("id"=>null, "description"=>null);

Comment: Initially there is a v-for list. From that a job is selected to open an initial modal - then if the job needs repricing, the PriceJob modal is opened on top of the first

Comment: @NikWhite, You have this code `v-model="job.price"` where is your `job` declared? Is `job` a property of `appData.jobs`?

Comment: @NikWhite, you should add information about `v-for` to the question because it is an important part of an issue.

Comment: So I need to add a v-for to pick up the job? If I add <span>{{job.id}}</span> I can see the job ID, so doesn't that mean that it already knows about the job to be repriced?

Comment: @NikWhite, I have made update to my answer. You shoud add some more code because it is unclear what you have and where you are calling your `showPriceJob` method.

Comment: @NikWhite, you can see `<span>{{job.id}}</span>` within your `v-for` loop but you can't assign something to your `job` variable within your method like `this.job = ...`.

Comment: I am not sure I quote follow you  - am I messing it up with my attempt to convert it to a number? Or is it because I am calling a child modal from a parent? If so, How can I pass through the information I need?

Comment: @NikWhite, I have made another update. Can you check it?

Comment: made the change and got 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'jobs' of undefined

Comment: @NikWhite, I have made third update to my answer. Can you check it?

Comment: still no luck I am afraid
ReferenceError: jobs is not defined